# how to add additional parameters in WSO2 API call

Tags: wso2

I am using WSO2 API manager 1.7. What I want is that when WSO2 API manager gets a REST API call then I want to pass 2 additional parameters to Endpoint gateway API. So e.g. API manager get 3 params then I want to pass 2 more static params to endpoint URL.
how can I achieve that, please help.

Thanks
Parvendra

Comment: I was trying to add 2 xml lines in in-sequence for particular API,so it is like <property name="additionalparam1">valhere</property>

Answer (score 0):

You can append a sequence to the exposed API and add these parameters in a header. You can add a sequence to the API Manager by following the doc below[1]. Similarly u can add the required header using a header mediator as shown in [2]

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Adding+Mediation+Extensions

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Header+Mediator

Comment: Nadeesha, I tried to follow instructions using [1] and it produced following error.0Status reportRuntime ErrorError while building message. I want to post 2 static values in post request to end point. also I have to use either [1] or [2], am I right?

Comment: I added following API sequence <sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="ParamsInURL:vamb--In">
    <log level="custom">
        <property name="TRACE" value="API Mediation Extension"/>
    </log>
</sequence> and it gave me following error org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in prolog. what may be the cause. I think hyphen in name is not valid,what are your views